# Set up security group for Windows Instance in AWS

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, rdp

I'm trying to connect my machine (MacOS) to a remote. I went on AWS and create a windows instance, I use the default security groups and downloaded the rdp file.

I open it with Microsoft Remote Destock and ends up with an error message:

`Unable to connect to remote PC. Please verify Remote Desktop is enabled, the remote PC is turned on and available on the network, and then try again.`

I tried to run the rdp file on a windows machine, I got the same error.

My question is: How do we set the security groups to open windows remotely.

Thanks

Comment: Does the instance pass its health checks?
Have you tried requesting a screen shot from the instance? (select instance in aws console, in "Actions" menu, "Instance Settings", then "Get instance screenshot"). You should see a Windows login screen. If the instance has networking issues, the login screen may display a yellow exclamation mark.
You should also confirm the VPC the instance has been launched into has an internet gateway, check the Network ACL's to confirm RDP traffic is allowed.

Comment: The instance successfully passed all the test. From the screenshot, I can see the windows login screen. I checked the VPC, RDP is set to allow. I checked the system log, I have this messages: 2018/04/06 09:42:56Z: Message: Windows is Ready to use
2018/04/06 09:43:19Z: Amazon SSM Agent v2.2.355.0 is running
2018/04/06 09:43:38Z: OsProductName: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
2018/04/06 09:43:38Z: OsInstallOption: Full

Comment: You might want enable vpc flow(firewall) logs. You should be able to see how far the connection gets.. You could also use the ssm run command to execute PowerShell script to test outbound connectivity from the instance.

Comment: Probably a silly question but are you able to rdp to another windows server to rule out any local firewall issues?

Comment: I created a log even in the CloudWatch. I don't really understand the messages. There are bunches of messages like this one 2 468786073381 eni-98f222b2 219.73.90.97 172.31.35.190 56475 5555 6 1 44 1523234283 1523234296 REJECT OK (sometime it is ACCEPT or REJECT). From the CloudWatch, everything seems to work well. I tried to launch another instance. I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

check your security group and make sure you have open RDP(3389)port.

Then you can generate your password by.

EC2 console --> Connect To Your Instance --> Get Password -->  Choose Browse and navigate to the private key file --> Decrypt Password.

The console displays the default administrator password for the instance in the Connect To Your Instance dialog box.

If you want to generate Remote Desktop File or details information you can go throught below link. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html

Comment: I open the port 3389 with the protocol: HTTP and source to anywhere (0.0.0.0/0, ::/0).  I followed the procedure and also check this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mf5u2chPBjY&t=1s I can't make it work.

Comment: You can select type to RDP from the security group or protocol TCP and port 3389. over HTTP protocol RDP not possible. and intend of open to (0.0.0.0/0, ::/0) you have to open for you IP range only that will be secure.

Comment: I change the source to myIP. Now it is Ports: 3389; Protocol: TCP; Source: 167.XXX.XXX (myIP). It still fails to connect

Comment: What error are you getting? have you reached to user login console?

Comment: After I open the rdp file, I get this error "Unable to connect to remote PC. Please verify Remote Desktop is enabled, the remote PC is turned on and available on the network, and then try again." I can't even access the login page

Comment: Are you facing this issue every time? have your instance health check passed I think this docs will be help on this:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/troubleshooting-windows-instances.html#rdp-issues